# Merging duplicate rows and relations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, duplicates

I am doing data migration which is pretty straight forward, but I ran into 'problem' with duplicate rows.

At our source system there was a so called "feature" that everytime user added new contact to client our system created new Contact row (and relation to client table via ClientContact) in our database. Now we are migrating our database and noticed that most rows in our Contact table are duplicates of just few (20 unique) rows.

We are using GUID as PK in our schema(in Client and in Contact table).  Client and Contact table are related to ClientContact table which only has PK's of Client and Contact tables.

I was wondering what is the easiest way to merge all of the rows in Contact table while maintaining the relationship to Client table.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What makes a Client "the same Client" as "this other row over here".?

Comment: What attributes did you use to identify that the rows are duplicate? was the entire row dup (except the pk) or only few key column which denote a row if dup of another row

Comment: Now relations are one-to-one and our goals is to get to one-to-many where one contact row connects to multiple clients. We used FirstName, LastName and  SalesId to identify dups (these are attributes that matter to us). Contact table has more attributes than these + PK.

Comment: In each set of duplicates identify a primary.  Point everything to the primary.  Then delete the duplicates.